# Lightweight Message Bus library

Tags: java, messaging

I will be starting a small Java (GWT really) project in the near future and I am at "information gathering" phase.

Q: Is there a lightweight Message Bus library written in Java?

My requirements are lightweight too :-)

1. async (no need for sync)
2. multicast and point-to-point
3. no strict message ordering
4. message "envelope" ideally "owned" by Message Bus (i.e. in terms of life-cycle management)
5. localized delivery (i.e. not inter-process nor inter-node)

**Update**: It seems that GWT now supports an integrated ["event bus"](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/mvp-architecture.html).

Comment: You can look here https://github.com/javaplugs/minibus it is extremely lightweight and simple event bus.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have a look at [eventbus](http://www.eventbus.org//).

(Link fixed; thanks to [jldupont](https://stackoverflow.com/users/171461/jldupont) to point that out).

Comment: You can also checkout https://github.com/bennidi/mbassador. It's very light-weight,fast and uses weak references.

Comment: @bennidi: You should post that as a new answer instead of using a comment

Answer (score 10):

I know this is an old question but I think a more modern solution is to use **[Guava's Event Bus](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained)** (granted I'm not sure if it will work for GWT but both your title and tags don't say GWT).

I actually have a custom [RabbitMQ simple message container](http://static.springsource.org/spring-amqp/reference/html/#d0e402) that will automatically create queue bindings and on messages received will then dispatch to Guava EventBus. Its incredible elegant, and scales superbly.

You can easily use your DI framework to register the Subscribers. For Spring I create BeanPostProcessor that will automatically registers beans with `@Subscribe`.

Below is the Spring BeanPostProcessor:

```
package com.snaphop.spring;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus;
import com.google.common.eventbus.Subscribe;

@Component
public class EventBusBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    private EventBus eventBus;

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if (isApplicable(bean)) {
            eventBus.register(bean);
        }
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }

    protected boolean isApplicable(Object bean) {
        for(Method m : bean.getClass().getMethods()) {
            if (m.isAnnotationPresent(Subscribe.class))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setEventBus(EventBus eventBus) {
        this.eventBus = eventBus;
    }

}
```

I'm sure is trivial to do something similar in Guice.

Comment: I have tried to use google guavas event bus and got stuck because it uses strong references to the listeners. I wanted to use it in a spring environment and just stuff all the beans into it using a post processor. This won't work with guava. I created my own solution which is hosted on github https://github.com/bennidi/mbassador. It's quite stable now (used in production for half a year) and is faster than the google bus. It also offers more features but is as easy to use.

Comment: I made my own implementation likewise but mainly because Guava uses JULI and I didn't like it catching the exception. I'll have to check out yours... I also noticed that Guava uses a collection of Class<?> which can potential lead to permgen leaks.

Comment: What do you mean by collection of Class<?> could lead to permgen leaks? Besides, I would really appreciate Feedback on MBassador. If it lacks a feature that you would require you can file an issue on github.

Comment: Actually, explicit checking for @Subscribe Annotations is not necessary with the Guava EventBus: https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/EventBusExplained#what-happens-if-i-register-a-listener-without-any-handler-methods

Answer (score 5):

If you happen to be using Spring already, then a handy sort-of-hidden feature of Spring is the [ApplicationEventMulticaster](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/ApplicationEventMulticaster.html) interface, which is a very simple API for publishing and subscribing to application-generated events. The implementations use the `TaskExecutor` framework, which means they can be sync or async as desired. Furthermore, every `ApplicationContext` has a `publishEvent` method, so it's comically easy to set it up for Spring-managed classes.

So yes, if you already use Spring, there's no need to for another utility to do this, it's built in already.

Comment: +1: many thanks. I won't be using Spring but I always value good information.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is really lightweight. But it does fit the rest of your description: [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/)

Comment: @reinier: I know about AMQP based solutions: (1) not lightweight (of course it is relative ;-) (2) not really applicable for a GWT based project.

Comment: @jldupont: ah right... it all has to run in the same process in the browser right?  Yes in that case ignore this idea ;^)

Comment: @reinier: then delete it as you'll likely get some down-votes at some point (not from me).

Comment: @jldupont: They tend to do that. ;^)    Still my wrong solution does add to the conversation for anyone else who might have come up with the same response

Comment: @reinier: have it your way then. Cheers :-)

Comment: you only need this connector for gwt. http://code.google.com/p/gwt-activemq/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try some jabber (XMPP) based solution. What about openfire?

Comment: @marcospereira: are you serious? it is not because I don't down-vote (often) that one can abuse here!

Comment: jldupont: yes, I'm serious. And I can't understand why you consider my comment as an abuse. If you think it is a wrong solution, put some arguments on the table. ;-)

Comment: actually xmpp is pretty cool, but maybe it has too much overhead