# Is Javaspaces supported on GWT?

Tags: java, gwt, javaspaces

Following a suggestion on a related post ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955623/pattern-matching-framework)), I was wondering if Javaspaces technology is supported on GWT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no. but it's possible to implement it on GWT. not sure anybody did that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on what you mean by "supported on GWT." GigaSpaces - built on JavaSpaces - can easily deploy GWT applications internally, and it's also easy for the server side of a GWT application to connect to a GigaSpace. (See http://openspaces.org/display/GDO/GoDo+-+Goods+Donation+System for an example of an application that does this - it was an OpenSpaces award winner.)

If you mean "direct from the client," well, it's likely to be POSSIBLE, but at that point you're not using the client side of GWT - you're using Java on the client.