# Switch between info/debug logs in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, logging, log4j

I want to dynamically switch between info/debug logs in production for my application running on a tomcat instance.

I am observing too many logs flooding our log files, so we ship with info, but if needed switch to debug for debugging. How should I do that in a dynamic fashion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this through JMX. If you are using log4j [here](https://code.google.com/p/logging-jmx-service/) is one option to expose a jmx mbean for log4j. [Log4j2](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/jmx.html) provides JMX support out of the box.

Comment: Is there a command line option, since i will have to monitor this on a remote Linux EC2 machine.

Comment: JConsole - a jmx client can be used to see/monitor the current log level. Through jmx & jconsole you can monitor and change log levels of remotely running java applications.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure there is an easy way to change logging levels ar runtime.
Logging levels are configured in tomcat_home/conf/logging.properties.
Supported levels are:

```
SEVERE, WARNING, INFO, CONFIG, FINE, FINER, FINEST or ALL
```

May be check this out [Reload tomcat logging at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141249/reload-tomcat-logging-at-runtime)